# Why is the background sometimes displayed and sometimes not?

Tags: html, css

I have CSS that underlines certain words.
Later I found that it didn't appear in the space.
I found that on the sample HTML, the underline is displayed between the upper `example`, but not between the lower `example`.
Why isn't the space below underlined?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .correct-line {
        background: linear-gradient(transparent 55%, rgb(10, 150, 126) 60%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>example<span class="correct-line"> </span>example</p>
    <hr />
    <div>
      example
      <span class="correct-line"> </span>example
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you use background-color in HTML? This might help you: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_background

Comment: Your code seems fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/kdvy60Lu/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because CSS processes multiple whitespaces into single space and space after newline character are both considered whitespace and hence reduced to single whitespace and 2nd whitespace is deleted. Contrast your code to below.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .correct-line {
        background: linear-gradient(transparent 55%, rgb(10, 150, 126) 60%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>example<span class="correct-line"> </span>example</p>
    <hr />
    <div>
      example<span class="correct-line"> </span>
example
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace for more info.

You can use `&nbsp;` if it's just your inserted data but presumably it's coming from a different source

You are probably better off using white-space:pre; as below

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .correct-line {
        background: linear-gradient(transparent 55%, rgb(10, 150, 126) 60%);
        white-space: pre;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>example<span class="correct-line"> </span>example</p>
    <hr />
    <div>
      example
      <span class="correct-line"> </span>example
    </div>
    <div>
      example<span class="correct-line">
       </span>example
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your code, whitespace in `span` is ignored when compiling html codes.
You need to use `&nbsp;` to represent the whitespace only.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      .correct-line {
        background: linear-gradient(transparent 55%, rgb(10, 150, 126) 60%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>example<span class="correct-line">&nbsp;</span>example</p>
    <hr />
    <div>
      example<span class="correct-line">&nbsp;</span>example
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP's code seems fine https://jsfiddle.net/kdvy60Lu/8/

Comment: That depends on browser and whitespace only ` ` can be ignored very easily on html browsers so it's safer to use `&nbsp` for whitespace only strings.

Comment: imagin how it'd be when there are multiple words in each row and when there's a text update or even adding new content. In my case this isn't a good solution.

Comment: If the text in `correct-line` span is something like `test test`, it will be fine to use the normal space but if the text is composed with several spaces like `    `, it can be ignorable so in that case, it should be written like `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`. My solution represented that case.